# How do I post a picture on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, images

I'd like to accompany my question with pictures, how do I do that?

Comment: Also, click the help icon, the question mark in the upper right of the "Your Answer" box.  It explains many formatting options, including images.

Comment: I don't mind an image as long as it isn't gigantic. Keep 'em small so they fit in with the page nicely. Crop out non-essential stuff so it's only what you want to talk about. I hate opening a question to find something that looks like a poster on the wall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The little polaroid icon that is 6th in line right above the answer input text area allows you to put a picture in:

[image: Screenshot of the picture icon in the toolbar]
<sub>(source: [mrozekma.com](http://so.mrozekma.com/toolbar-picture.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

- Click on the polaroid button (Ctrl-K) to upload images to imgur, both from the web (goes around referrer surprises) or your computer.
- 1. Click on the link button (Ctrl-L) to insert a plain boring link to an image:

     ```
     [link text][1]
     ```
  2. Prepend the link with an exclamation point:

     ```
     ![link text][1]
     ```

  You have a direct image link to your URL of choice!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use HTML syntax, eg

`<img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png">`

[image]

Comment: is it possible to set the height and width of these images? HTML syntax or other?

Comment: Yes, just add width="100" or height="100"